# Is there a STDDEV equivalent in Cloud Spanner functions?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I don't see it in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators); is it perhaps part of an existing function I didn't notice, or available in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrei Tigau mentioned, STDDEV is not supported yet. That said, you need to calculate it in two pass. Assuming you are interested in column x of YourTable,

```
SELECT SQRT(SUM(POW(x - avg, 2)/(n-1)))
FROM (SELECT AVG(x) AS avg, COUNT(*) AS n FROM YourTable)
  CROSS JOIN YourTable;
```

You may try following one pass solution as well.

```
SELECT SQRT(s2/(n-1) - POW(s/n, 2))
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS n, SUM(x) AS s, SUM(x*x) AS s2
  FROM YourTable
);
```

Depending on type, you may have to cast it to double (especially for s2) to avoid overflow. Both will suffer from floating point errors.

Answer (score 0):

This function does not exist in the official documentation that you have send, so probably it still doesn't exist. If you need something like that you should probably calculate the standard deviation by yourself programmaticaly. You have the [AVG function](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#avg) that helps you get at least the median value which will be helpful in the calculation of the standard deviation and the [COUNT](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#count) function for the number of entries.

```
double standardDeviation ; // standard deviation
double sumOfDiffrences = 0; 

for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ){

sumOfDiffrences = sumOfDiffrences + pow((entry(i)-avg),2); // entry(i) is an entry of the column you want to create the S.D.

}
standardDeviation = sqrt((sumOfDiffrences)/(count-1));
```

Comment: You can also file a feature request for this product if you feel it will be really useful : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190851

Answer (score 0):

`STDDEV` is supported since 2020-06-03.

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/release-notes?hl=en#June_03_2020